# How to calculate sum of numbers from a file?

Tags: java, android, filereader

I want to show the sum of all the numbers added from a file in TextView, currently it just reads/shows the last number from the file.

This is my current code for writing to a file:

```
total.setText(total.getText());                            
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("TotalSavings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(total.getText().toString().getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is my current code for reading from a file:

```
public void savingstotalbutton(View view) {

        try {
            BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    openFileInput("TotalSavings")));
            String inputString;
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();                
            while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(inputString + "\n");
            }
            savingstotaltext.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }               
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Use `Scanner` to read data from file.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273908/calculating-sum-of-numbers-from-a-file

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the only thing on the line is an integer, can't you do something like this?

```
public void savingstotalbutton(View view) {

    int total = 0;

    try {
        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                openFileInput("TotalSavings")));
        String inputString;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();                
        while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
            //stringBuffer.append(inputString + "\n");
            total = total + Integer.parseInt(inputString);
        }
        //savingstotaltext.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
        savingstotaltext.setText(String.ValueOf(total));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }               
}
```

**Edit:** Extended answer per questions in comments

Just change `int total` to `double total` and `Integer.parseInt()` to `Double.parseDouble()` if you are using decimals.  Also, if there are more characters on the line than digits/decimals, try using the following to only strip out and use the numbers as well as ensure there is content on the line:

```
if (inputString.length() > 0) {
    String line = inputString.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");
    total = total + Double.parseDouble(line);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that but the numbers are not integers they are prices e.g. £18.95 , £50 etc. so do I have to change it to double?

Comment: Yeah, that should be fine as long as you don't have any other characters such as: £.  If you do, you will need to strip out any other characters to make sure the data type conversion from `string` succeeds.

Comment: @OlympicBeast I edited my answer to point you in the right direction.  Let me know if you need any clarification.  If my answer helped you, please accept it.

Comment: Sorry just saw your edit. Also I am seeing this error on Eclipse LogCat: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Comment: @OlympicBeast Sounds like from that error you have an empty value somewhere.  Make sure all of your variables are initialized and consistent. It is probably because you are trying to parse a double/integer from an empty value (an empty line).  See my edit for that as well as stripping out the currency sign.  Using `replaceAll()`, you can strip out only digits/decimals.

Comment: I fixed the error and installed the app again on the simulator but it is not adding the prices it still only shows the last price saved in the file.

Comment: @OlympicBeast are you sure there is not a problem with your list?  Are you sure you are using `total = total + ...`.  The code above should work fine.  You may have to open up another question, because we have a long comment thread going and you are unable to chat due to your reputation.