# Calculating sum of numbers from a file?

Tags: java, android, io

I want to show the sum of all prices (e.g. £18.99 £50 etc.) from a file in a TextView, currently it just reads/shows the last price from the file.

This is my current code for writing to a file:

```
total.setText(total.getText());                            
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("TotalSavings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(total.getText().toString().getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is my current code for reading from a file (member burmat suggested some changes):

```
public void savingstotalbutton(View view) {

        double total = 0;

        try {
            BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    openFileInput("TotalSavings")));
            String inputString;
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();                
            while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {

                if (inputString.length() > 0) {
                String line = inputString.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");
                total = total + Double.parseDouble(line);
                }
            }
            savingstotaltext.setText(String.valueOf(total));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }               
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**
I modified the contents of the TotalSavings.txt manually and added different prices and copied that to the /files folder of the App. It reads all the prices and gives the sum which works but the problem is that the write function overwrites the 1st line, it never goes to the next line.

**Edit 2:** The whole code which uses calc button to show calculation and the write the result to the file TotalSavings.txt

```
public void calc(View view) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        if (price.getText().toString().equals(""))
            return;
        if (disc.getText().toString().equals(""))
            return;
        double priceVal = Double.parseDouble(price.getText().toString());
        double discVal = Double.parseDouble(disc.getText().toString());
        double discount = priceVal / 100.0 * discVal;
        int di = (int) (discount * 100);
        double totalVal = priceVal - (di / 100.0);
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        savings.setText(nf.format(discount));
        total.setText(nf.format(totalVal));

        savings.setText(savings.getText());                            
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("TotalSavings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(savings.getText().toString().getBytes());         
        fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you show me the file you are trying to read please?

Comment: @Paul Harris the file name is TotalSavings.txt and it contains one line which is: $455.88   Basically the write function does not go to the next line it rewrites the 1st line all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your problem with writing to the file is every time you are writing to the file you are over writing what was there before, what you need to do is change

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("TotalSavings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

to:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("TotalSavings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE | Context.MODE_APPEND)
```

This tells android you want to append to the file as well as keep it private.

*EDIT*
You new issue is because you are placing the text directly after the other text, you want to force a new line into your file. The simplest way will be something like:

```
String totalFromField = total.getText().toString() + "\n";
fos.write(totalFromField.getBytes());
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I just made the changes. When I run the App, and save a price it shows back the price, but when I save another price (for the 2nd time) and press the savingstotalbutton the application crashes and does not show the total sum. Eclipse Log Cat shows the following errors: FATAL EXCEPTION: main , Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "84.48845.46" , at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need this line

```
String line = inputString.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");
```

Instead you must say

```
String line = inputString;
```

It must work for you.

Comment: I use  String line = inputString.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");  because the file contains currency signs.

Comment: In this case your expression is not correct. Could you check your expression again? There is a problem with your regular expression.

Comment: This link might help you a little.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252626/need-a-simple-regex-to-find-a-number-in-a-single-word

Comment: Thanks for the link, I checked it and the expression is fine. I think the problem might be in the file.

Comment: Don't forget to escape the dot! Or else, it will match any character.

Comment: @jlordo I tried it still doesnt work, only reads the last price in the file and shows that in the TextView.

Comment: if you replace `savingstotaltext.setText(String.valueOf(total));` with `savingstotaltext.setText("foo");`, will it display foo?

Comment: @jlordo yes it displays foo.

Comment: are you sure your file has more than one line?

Comment: also try to log all your intermediate values of `total`

Comment: @jlordo Is there a way to check it? because I can't find the file as I am running it on the Android Emulator.

Comment: Where does the file come from? How did it get into the emulator? also you could initialize a counter outside of the loop, increment it in the loop and set your text as the counter value, than you know the number of lines. - looking at your code it seems your file has only one line (which is also the last).

Comment: @jlordo Yes you are right, I managed to get the text file from \data\data path through adb commands and it only had one line, so the function overwrites the current line and doesn't go to next line.